# Simulator for multiple modbus slaves

Tags: tcp, simulator, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus3

Hello is there any tcp modbus slave simulator that could simulate 3 slaves simultaneously from one pc? Is it possible?

The main concept is that i have to deal with a plc that controls some VFD although i want to imitate those VFD and give the feedback of those 3 back to plc from my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start 3 instances of the ModRSsim program but on a single computer it is not possible for more than one program to listen for connections on the same TCP port number.

Therefore, only one of the instances can use the standard Modbus 502 TCP port and the other two must use another port number.